# Duty cycle in Sine PWM and Conduction Losses in a MOSFET

Tags: pwm, inverter

I'm trying to understand an analytical expression for conduction losses in an MOSFET based inverter. In the derivation given in a paper, the usual starting point is the definition of the duty cycle:

"Assuming a naturally sampled PWM sine-triangle modulation, the duty cycle as a function of α can be deﬁned as

$$D(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2} (1 + M \text{sin}(\alpha)) $$

where
$$\alpha = 2\pi t /T$$
D is the duty cycle, T is the period and M is the modulation index."

I find it hard to understand the background of this equation.

---

Paper: [Analytical Conduction Loss Calculation of a MOSFET Three-Phase Inverter Accounting for the Reverse Conduction and the Blanking Time](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=9126257)

This is equation (3) on page 2 of this paper.

Comment: Please provide a link to the paper you read so that your question has proper context.

Comment: Here it is: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9126257. This is equation (3) on page 2 of this paper.

Comment: What do you find hard to understand about it?

Comment: Duty cycle is some percentage of the switching period, right? But here, for every time instant, a new value is defined. That's what I don't understand.

Comment: I think the calculation is close to what you do for PFCs and conduction losses: in a PFC, you calculate the switch rms current \$I_d\$ over a switching period which depends on the duty ratio \$d\$. However, \$d\$ is modulated along the grid line period therefore \$d\$ in the equation of the rms current becomes a time-dependent variable and \$I_d\$ becomes \$i_d(t)\$. You now integrate along the line period to obtain the instantaneous conduction loss averaged along a line period. Have a look at this [document](http://u.dianyuan.com/bbs/u/0/1065598993.pdf) for the principle with PFC as guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Simply skip this Eq. (1) with its arcane definition of 'duty cycle', as this D(α) never appears further on, and you can proceed to where the equation (9) is derived.

First, the authors introduce the parallel conduction angle β, the angle φ of displacement power factor, and the peak value I (with hat) of the phase current. Then, they shift the integration interval [0, 2π) (referred to a single inverter sine wave) by the angle φ and partition it into two sub-intervals, [-β, π + β) and [π + β, 2π - β). The angle β being the parallel conduction angle, means that MOSFETs and diodes are switched at the boundaries of these sub-intervals, and in each of these sub-intervals the current \$i_T\$ is represented by a simple analytic expression, either \$i_{T,1}\$ or \$i_{T,2}\$, respectively. In a similar way, they transform the equation (2) for diode conduction losses, never using D(α) explicitly, too.

So, if you experience difficulty of perceiving the authors' concept of 'duty cycle' (as I also do), you can simply ignore it. The only other moment the authors resort to their interpretation of 'duty cycle' is the equation (12) where a third harmonic is introduced. Again, the derivation of actual formulas (27) and (28) in Appendix never uses D(α).

Comment: I was unnecessarily focusing on this. 
Thank you for the detailed explanation.